# Excel formula to sum at the end of each date

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel spreadsheet with four columns ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9jUV.png)), which are `date`, `start time`, `end time`, `time spent`. `time spent` is equal to `end time - start time`. I would like a fifth column which lists the total time spent for each day. This total should appear next to the last entry for a given day ([like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWPRf.png)) and otherwise the column should be blank. How can I achieve this in Excel?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
E2: =IF(A2=A3,"",SUMIF($A$2:$A$100,A2,$D$2:$D$100))
```

and fill down

Comment: This solution worked for me. I had to make sure to format the output column as 'date' (the default formatting produced incorrect results).